# Print index of a list that contains a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing, python-3.7

I would like to print the second index of a list. In this particular case, it would be Col3. However, I am getting the error

***---> 13 df_learn.index(2)***

***TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable***

Here's what I am attempting.

```
import pandas as pd

df_learn = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   'Col2': [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   'Col3': [17, 27, 22, 37, 52],
                   'Col4': [34, 7, 12, 44, 21]})

df_learn.index(2)
```

My list actually has a dictionary inside, so how would I print a particular index it in this case?

When I do something like:

```
df_learn1 = df_learn[:1]
print(df_learn1)
```

I do get index 0 printed. Why would this work but not for a particular index?
The following did not work either...

```
print(df_learn[2])
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line it will work.

```
    df_learn.iloc[:, 2]#to get column values of 2nd index
    #df_learn.iloc[2] #to get 2nd element of each column
```

Or this

```
    df_learn['Col3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try `df_learn['col3']` the number that you want. This is because you acctaully have a list inside your dictionary not the other way around.